# Understand `this` in Constructor Invocation Pattern

Tags: javascript

Trying to understand `this`, found an example in `javascript the good parts` book:

```
var first;
var second;

var Quo = function(string) {
    first = this;
    this.status = string;// first this
};

Quo.prototype.get_status = function() {
    second = this;
    return this.status;//second this
};

var myQuo = new Quo( "confused" );
console.log( myQuo.get_status() );

console.log( (first===second) + ',' + (second===myQuo) + ',' + (first===myQuo) );
```

Output:

```
$ node test.js 
confused
true,true,true
```

Does the first `this` and the second `this` both point to `myQuo`? How to print out the object name or function name or class name which each `this` point to? (Really confused by `this` currently.)

**UPDATE**

Another questions: Both `this` refer to the instance of Quo instead of Quo's prototype?

Also, trying:

```
console.log( myQuo.get_status() );
console.log(first.constructor.name);
console.log( first );
console.log( second );
```

Output:

```
confused

{ status: 'confused' }
{ status: 'confused' }
```

Why `first.constructor.name` is nothing? Why `first` is `{ status: 'confused' }`?

Comment: `this` means the instance within a constructor.

Comment: @dandavis They should all be pointing to the same instance, `myQuo`. Your comment doesn't really make sense

Comment: What is the first andsecond this? Which ones do you refer to?

Comment: @JuanMendes: yeah, i misread it, there is only one instance.

Comment: To answer your first question: yes. To answer your second question - you can try to do `console.log(first)` and `console.log(second)` which will give you an object. Not sure what else is there to say here, though.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Comment: Please don't ask two questions in one post http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions Makes it hard for a single answer to be correct and makes it less useful to others

Comment: @JuanMendes I got three trues too.

Comment: @BAE OK, I was going crazy, I swear I sahad seen true, true, false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript, when a function defined on a prototype is called on an instance; "this" inside the function means (think like it is replaced with-) that instance (or the owning object having the prototype in its prototype chain).

In your case the constructor (which is also a function on the prototype) is called with a newly created object as "this" with the "new" keyword.

```
var Quo = function(string) {
    first = this; //this is the newly created instance
    this.status = string;// first this
};
```

Then first is also assigned the exact same instance.

When get_status is called on the same instance, this is again replaced with the instance;

```
Quo.prototype.get_status = function() {
    second = this; //this is myQuo
    return this.status;//second this
};
```

and this time second is assigned the same instance.

doing myQuo.get_status() is same as;

```
Quo.prototype.get_status.call(myQuo)
```

Therefore these two "this" keywords refer to the same object.

Doing the "===" check is perfectly fine to compare if two variables point to the same instance. Getting the constructor name just tell you they were constructed with a specific constructor name, not else. It is possible to make two different objects with the same constructor name.

Comment: both `this` refer to the instance of Quo instead of Quo's prototype?

Comment: Yes, they refer to the instance.

Comment: Exactly. Think about calling the functions on the prototype with .call or .apply with the object instance as "this".

Comment: It really has nothing to do with `Object.prototype` that the `this` context gets replaced, in that `Object.prototype` is not unique. It has to do with the fact that the function `get_status` is being called on an owning object, therefore the this context is set to that of the owning object.

Comment: "*when a function defined on a prototype is called; the lexical "this" inside the function means (think like it is replaced with-) the instance of that prototype object*" is not necessarily true. *this* is set by how a function is called, or use of *bind*. The only lexical *this* is from arrow functions. The function declaration in the answer is not syntactically correct.

Comment: I'm the king of edits now. I think the last version is as close as I can get :)

Comment: @RobG To expand on my comment, I have posted an answer. I think you'll like it

Answer (score 2):

This question is solely centered around `this` and `context` within JavaScript.

Whenever you question **What is `this`?** You should always ask yourself these 4 questions (in order) and you will always get your answer.

1. Was the function called with the `new` keyword?

   Example: `var myObj = new Obj();`

   This: The newly created object
2. Was the function called with `call`, `apply`, or `bind` with the `this`
   context explicitly passed?

   Example: `myFunction.call(self)`

   This: `this` inside myFunction will be equal to `self`
3. Was the function called via a containing/owning object?

   Example: `myObj.myFunction()`

   This: `this` inside myFunction will be equal to `myObj`
4. What is the default `this` context?

   This: If in **strict-mode**, default is *undefined*. If **not in strict-mode**, default is the *global object*

So, in your case:

`first = this` is inside the Quo function, and is called using the "new" keyword, therefore `first` will equal the newly created object.

`myQuo` is simply the return value of executing the Quo function with the "new" keyword, which returns the newly created object by default, so that is why `first === myQuo`

`second = this` is inside of the `get_status()` function, which means nothing until the function is called. Once the function is called, you can see **question 3** above, to see that the `this` context will be bound to the owning object. Since it was called with `myQuo.get_status()`, myQuo is the owning object, which is why `second === myQuo`.

Hopefully this clears everything up! Let me know if you need additional explanation!

Comment: P.S. I have these 4 questions written on a sticky note which sits on my monitor at all times for reference - quite handy!

Comment: 4. is confusing. _Am I running strict mode? Context:  this will default to the global object (except in strict mode)_ How to run strict mode except strict mode? Also the example is not complete.

Comment: @AliNaciErdem Your comment is pretty nit-picky, to be honest.. especially the strict-mode example being incomplete. I'm not here to explain how strict mode works. I did re-word the question, though, to remove any ambiguity.

Comment: You forgot to mention fat arrow (for completeness), it doesn't matter how it's called

Comment: @mhodges I also found that if `myQuo.get_status()` not called, second is undefined. I am confused. I thought the object `Quo.prototype` already exists before `myQuo.get_status()` called.

Comment: Note that "context" typically refers to an execution context. *this* is just one parameter of an execution context, it's not **the** context. Instead of "*…the this context will…*" you should just say "*…this will…*". ;-)

Comment: @RobG That's a fair point. I think saying the "this context" would be correct, but I think it could be confusing when I just say "context". I will change it accordingly. Thanks for the insight

Comment: @BAE The reason it is undefined before you call `myQuo.get_status()` is because code inside of a function never gets executed before it is invoked. Therefore, `second`'s value will be determined at run time of the function. If you were to invoke it on myQuo2, second would be equal to myQuo2.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the first this and the second this both point to myQuo?

Correct they both point to the same instance of `Quo`.

> How to print out the object name or function name or class name which each this point to?

```
console.log(first.constructor.name);
console.log(second.constructor.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an explanation of how `this` works in the two cases you mentioned. First, you need to understand that `this` is set depending on how the function is called (unless we're dealing with [fat arrow functions](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html) )

## When calling `new`

```
var myQuo = new Quo( "confused" );
```

It's basically the same as doing

```
var myQuo = Object.create(Quo.prototype);
// Explicitly setting `this`
Quo.call(myQuo, "confused")
```

## When calling a function on an object

```
myQuo.get_status()
```

Implies that the `get_status` function will be called with what's to the left of the `.`, that is, `myQuo`.

- You can never now the name of an object (if you mean that this is named `myQuo`)
- To get a reference to the constructor function, you can do `myQuo.constructor` (or `this.constructor`). If your function is named (as yours is), you can use `this.constructor.name` to get `Quo`.

Comment: Your answer lacks completeness by omitting call, apply, bind, and default this context

Comment: @mhodges But my answer explains that I'm only talking about the cases the OP mentioned, I did not attempt to give a thorough explanation as your answer did ;) `Here's an explanation of how this works in the two cases you mentioned` I only added that comment to your answer because you did attempt a thorough explanation.