# jQuery - text deleted by .html() when targeting element directly but not when using .each()

Tags: jquery

I've got a hard time understanding why one version of my code is working, while the other one isn't.

**Background info:**
I've got some text strings that hold the following character in it, to separate one part of the text from another: `|`

My goal is to wrap the text following this character in a `<span>` which is also working with the code beneath, using jQuery `.each()`. However, as I have single elements (the original element can be on each page up to 40 times) that also contains this text, and needs the same process, I wanted to target these "individually" (not looping through all of them). However, when I target the elements individually the entire text of the element is deleted rather than being wrapped / replaced. You can see the code that is not working a little further down, and in the bottom an example.

I've got the following code which is working as intended/imagined:

```
// This part works fine 

$('.aa').each(function() {
$(this).html($(this).text().replace('| ', '<span>')).append('</span>');
});
```

This part is not working as imagined:

```
// Not working as imagined

$(".bb").html($(this).text().replace('| ', '<span>')).append('</span>');
```

Here's a live example:

```js
// This part works fine 
$('.aa').each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).text().replace('| ', '<span>')).append('</span>');
});


// This part does not work as imagined?
setTimeout(function(){
// ---------------
$(".bb").html($(this).text().replace('| ', '<span>')).append('</span>');
// ---------------
},3000)
```

```css
span{
  color:red;
  display:block;
}
.aa{
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="aa">
Hi | There</div>

<div class="bb">
a | b
</div>
```

**Question:**
Why doesn't the last code work as I would have imagined, and rather than replacing the text it completely deletes it all?
And on another note, is there a better way of wrapping the remaining text than the one I'm using?

**Additional question**
Following up on the splendid answers given, I've got another question:
Since it's not possible to use the `$(this)` selector like this due to scope issues, how would one then target multiple elements such as this:

```
$(".bb, .cc").html($(this).text().replace('| ', '<span>')).append('</span>');
```

Note that I'm aware that the above piece is incorrect - but the `$(this)` part is just to underline my question as to how you should target those different elements. Is it optimal to use the `.each()` function for this purpose?


For sake of answering other people's problem regarding this matter: The answer for the additional question is "yes" to the use of `.each()` based on the comment of @mhodges in the answer from @woodrow

Comment: `this` context refers to the global object (likely `window`) in 2nd example. It refers to the current jQuery element in the `.each()`

Comment: @mhodges man i would've never catched that one :O So, replacing `$(this)` with `$(".bb")` actually solves it and works as I would have imagined. Could you possibly explain why?

Comment: try `var bb = $(".bb"); bb.html(bb.text.replace(...)).append(...);` instead

Comment: Your functions aren't equivalent. In the first, `this` is in the same scope both times. In the second, you've replaced one `this` with $(".bb"), presumably because you realize doing $(this).innerHTML would refer to something generic - the window. But this applies to the second one as well. In the second example, the functions are *chained*, not nested. In the first, they are nested, not chained.

Comment: Kind of a lengthy explanation if you are unfamiliar with the concept of context. Basically, the `this` keyword refers to different things depending on the calling context in which it is used. I can point you to some references if you'd like to get a deeper understanding

Comment: That would be neat @mhodges - although you shouldn't be wasting your time on it if you have to find the references first, as I could do that my self, now that I know what i'm looking for  :-)

Comment: @Chri.s Here's a link to a [stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40556348/4987197) I posted a while back. Also, check out Kyle Simpson's [YDKJS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/README.md#you-dont-know-js-this--object-prototypes) book on `this` and object prototypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see below. The "$(this)" inside of your setTimeout is referring to the scope within the setTimeout function, which could be "window", which isn't valid, whereas "$(this)" inside of the each statement for "aa" refers to each "aa" element in the loop. You need to reference "bb" as the class inside the setTimeout function..

```js
// This part works fine 
$('.aa').each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).text().replace('| ', '<span>')).append('</span>');
});


// This part does not work as imagined?
setTimeout(function() {
  // ---------------
  $(".bb").html($(".bb").text().replace('| ', '<span>')).append('</span>');
  // ---------------
}, 3000)
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
  display: block;
}

.aa {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="aa">
  Hi | There</div>

<div class="bb">
  a | b
</div>
```

Comment: It's definitely working - but removing the `setTimeout` function doesn't change it's behaviour, so why doesn't it target the `.bb` class? Just looking for some clarification

Comment: Because "this" is referring to the scope of the window, not the actual bb element. Please see this for more on js scope: https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/

Comment: Scoping in JS is done by functions.

Your first example, `$(this).html($(this).text().replace('| ', '<span>')).append('</span>');` is nested inside the function `$('.aa').each()`

So `this` is handled by `$.each` which is likely explicitly setting it to be the specific element of that iteration.

In your second example, `$(".bb").html($(".bb").text().replace('| ', '<span>')).append('</span>');` is nested within `setTimeout` which isn't equipped to handle `this`

Comment: Ah! Thank you. But then how would one go about it, if you had to target multiple elements such as this: `$(".bb, .cc").html($(this).text().replace('| ', '<span>')).append('</span>');`. I know that the code isn't correct, but is it even possible to do it like this, when you can't use the `$(this)` target? I will update my question with this as well, in case you feel like answering it :-)

Comment: @Chri.s That's when you would use `.each()`. And in that case, jQuery internally sets the `this` context to the current DOM element for that iteration of the loop. This is not default JS behavior - that's a jQuery thing. Normally, the `this` context would be set to the owning/containing object that `.forEach()` was called on (as per my stack answer I listed in the comments on the original question)

Comment: @mhodges thank you very much for the clarification and help - it's perfect and I appreciate it!